# Getting 400 errors for cookie length but nginx setting large_client_header_buffers seems to be ignored

Tags: cookies, nginx

I've set my nginx conf to an eye-wateringly high level but it still blocks my requests with: "400 Bad request  Your browser sent an invalid request." when I set my cookies to be anywhere above ~8k in size.

```
http {
...
client_body_buffer_size      128k;
large_client_header_buffers 64 512k;
}
...
```

Any idea what setting I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't NGinx at all, it was the Haproxy underneath.  Setting tune.bufsize fixed it:

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn         4096
    tune.bufsize 128000
    ...
```